# How to silence android phone based on set time

Tags: android, time, timer, timepicker

I'm trying to write a program that will silence a phone based on a time. So for instance, I press a button the I can set a start time and end time. At that start time the phone will silence. At that end time the phone will go back to regular ringer mode. Currently it will silence the phone but not go back to regular mode once it hits the end time. I have a lot of things commented out from previous attempts at trying to solve this issue. The uncommented parts is what I currently have. I really would like some help/guidance on this issue.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PresetEdit extends Activity
{
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private boolean mPhoneIsSilent;
    Button save;
    private Button startTime;
    private Button endTime;

    private int sHour;
    private int sMinute;
    private int eHour;
    private int eMinute;

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID2 = 1;

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener sTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    sHour = hourOfDay;
                    sMinute = minute;
                    updateDisplay();
                    displayToast();
                }
            };

            private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener eTimeSetListener =
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            eHour = hourOfDay;
                            eMinute = minute;
                            updateDisplayE();
                            displayToastE();
                        }
                    };       


            private void updateDisplay() {
                startTime.setText(
                    new StringBuilder()
                            .append(pad(sHour)).append(":")
                            .append(pad(sMinute)));

            }        
            private void updateDisplayE(){
                endTime.setText(new StringBuilder()
                                        .append(pad(eHour)).append(":")
                                        .append(pad(eMinute)));
            }
            private void displayToast() {
                Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ").append(startTime.getText()),   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            private void displayToastE() {
                Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ").append(endTime.getText()),   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            private static String pad(int c) {
                if (c >= 10)
                    return String.valueOf(c);
                else
                    return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
            }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preset_edit);

        TextView eventTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewEvent);
        startTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStartTime);
        endTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEndTime);

         startTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });

         endTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID2);
                }
            });

         final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            sHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            sMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            updateDisplay();

            final Calendar calE = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar tmp = (Calendar)calE.clone();
            tmp.add(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
            tmp.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
            //eHour = calE.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            Calendar stopTime = tmp;
            //eMinute = calE.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            eHour = tmp.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            eMinute = tmp.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            updateDisplayE();


        //save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        //get event txt to change according to button click

        /*Bundle car = getIntent().getExtras();
        String receivingdata = car.getString("eventCar");
        TextView eventTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.event);
        eventTxt.setText(receivingdata);*/

        /*Intent a = getIntent();
        a.getStringExtra("eventDrive");*/

        String drv = getIntent().getExtras().getString("event");
        if(drv!=null)
        {
            eventTxt.setText(drv); 

            Time now = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            //Time end = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            Time current = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            //Time setToEnd = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            current.setToNow();

            now.setToNow();
            //now.hour = 6;
            //now.minute = 35;
            //String sTime = ""+ now.hour+":"+now.minute;
            //startTime.setText(sTime);
            //end.hour = now.hour;
            //end.minute = now.minute + 2;
            //String eTime = ""+ end.hour+":"+end.minute;
            //endTime.setText(eTime);
            //setToEnd.hour = eHour;
            //setToEnd.minute = 13;
            if (sHour == now.hour && sMinute == now.minute) 
            {

                mAudioManager =(AudioManager)PresetEdit.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                //or adjust volume here instead setting silent profile for the ringer




            }
            if(current.hour == eHour && current.minute == eMinute)
            {
                mAudioManager =(AudioManager)PresetEdit.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

            }




        }//end if


        String mov = getIntent().getExtras().getString("event");
        if(mov!=null)
            eventTxt.setText(mov);

        String study = getIntent().getExtras().getString("event");
        if(study!=null)
            eventTxt.setText(study);

        String act = getIntent().getExtras().getString("event");
        if(act!=null)
            eventTxt.setText(act);




        /*Intent intent = getIntent();
        String text = intent.getStringExtra("eventDriving");*/
        //eventTxt.setText(text);
    }
    /*private void setButtonClickListener() {
         save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mPhoneIsSilent) {
                    //change back to normal mode
                    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = false;
                    save.setText("Activate");
                }
                else
                {
                    //change to silent mode
                    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    //mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = true;
                    save.setText("Activated");
                }
                // Now toggle the UI again

            }
        });
    }

     private void checkIfPhoneIsSilent() {
            int ringermode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();
            if (ringermode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
                mPhoneIsSilent = true;
            }
            else
            {
                mPhoneIsSilent = false;
            }
        }

     @Override      
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            checkIfPhoneIsSilent();

        }*/

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
                case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                sTimeSetListener, sHour, sMinute, false);

                case TIME_DIALOG_ID2:
                    return new TimePickerDialog(this, 
                            eTimeSetListener, eHour, eMinute, true);
        }
    return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you expact to RINGER_MODE_NORMAL line will execute in you code?? I think you need AlarmManager Api in android, start the alarm...do silent the phone...set the time after the alarm will invoke again...and unsilent the then...

Comment: So your saying once the alarm starts, silence the phone. Then set the end time for the alarm to start again and unsilent the phone? @umair.ali

Comment: I mean...silent the phone...initiate the alarm with time...and unsilent the phone when alarm invokes..

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html) - it will serve. The problem lies in the fact that aktiviti not exists at the time, how to turn the sound on.

Answer (score 0):

lets to these steps...

1. Create the intent service to unsilent the phone

   ```
   public class SetToNormalService extends IntentService {
     public SetToNormalService(String name) { super(name); }
     public SetToNomralService() { super(null); }
     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       // set the phone ringer to normal
       mAudioManager =(AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
           mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
     }
   }
   ```
2. In your button event, set the phone silent and initiate AlarmManager

   ```
   public void SilentAndSetAlarm(Context context,long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis) {
     // set the phone to silent
     mAudioManager =(AudioManager)PresetEdit.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
           mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
     // Initialize the AlarmManager
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, SetToNomralService.class);
     PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, pIntent);
   }
   ```

Thats All...

**NOTES:**
You dont neet to call any of the constructor...but if you remove the one with parameter 'name', it will throw an exception...so leave it as it is...

And for millis...you can use

```
    //get current time object
    Date date = new Date();
    // set its hours and mimuts that you got from time picker
    date.setHours(hoursOfDay);
    date.setMinutes(minutesOfDay);
    //getTime will give you millisecond of date object
    long timeInMillis = date.getTime();
```

in this way...you can convert you eHours and eMinutes to millis for both, startTime and intervalTime...

Comment: Which button event are you referring to? @umair.ali

Comment: Any button you want, preferably after getting start and end time form time picker...convert these time to milis...and call the method above like this...SilentAndSetAlarm(context, startTime, endTime);

Comment: do I actually need both of these: public SetToNormalService(String name) { super(name); }
  public SetToNomralService() { super(null); }
? The super(name) gives me a call must be first statement in constructor but I've tried every way. Also when you say convert the time to millis. How would I do that? My start times are sHour and sMinute, end times are eHour and eMinute. I'm not sure how to convert those to millis and get them into the startTime and endTime variables to call the SilentAndSetAlarm. If you don't mind helping me with this last piece I would greatly appreciate it! @umair.ali

Comment: You dont neet to call any of the constructor...but if you remove the one with parameter 'name', it will throw an exception...so leave it as it is...and for millis...you can use

        Date date = new Date();
        date.setHours(hoursOfDay);
        date.setMinutes(minutesOfDay);
        long timeInMillis = date.getTime();

Comment: Fixed my constructor issue, now the issue I'm having is that the date.setHours, minutes is deprecated and it gives me an IllegalArgumentException error. @umair.ali

Comment: http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.1_r1_src/java/sql/Date.html#setHours(int) This site says that it will always throw this exception. Now converting those values to what I need won't work using the Date class @umair.ali